# Is there a way to call a function with different number of variables?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, std-function

I would like to design a way to call one of many very similar functions - where the only difference is the number of arguments. Bare in mind this is a minimal example of my larger issue. I have lots of functions for doing different tasks. Each function prototype is very similar - except they have a different number of parameters.

I want to be able to call some wrapper class that I tell it the test type and pass it a list (vector) of params and it sorts the rest out for me.

Here is a working setup (with the parts that don't work commented out):

```
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

enum class test_type {t0, t1, t2, t3, t4, tn};

class tester
{
public:
    void run(test_type type, const std::vector<int> &args)
    {
        func_map[type].func();
    };

private:    
    void function_0()                       { std::cout << "f0\n"; };
    void function_1(int p1, int p2)         { std::cout << "f1\n"; };
    void function_2(int p1, int p2, int p3) { std::cout << "f2\n"; };
    void function_3(int p1, int p2)         { std::cout << "f3\n"; };
    void function_4(int p1)                 { std::cout << "f4\n"; };
    void function_n(int p1)                 { std::cout << "fn\n"; };


    struct test_info
    {
        std::function<void()> func; // variadic function std::function<void(...)> ?
        int num_params;
    };

    std::map<test_type, test_info> func_map {
        {test_type::t0, {[this]{function_0();}, 0}}
        // {test_type::t1, {[this]{function_1();}, 2}}
        // {test_type::t2, {[this]{function_2();}, 3}}
        // {test_type::t3, {[this]{function_3();}, 2}}
        // {test_type::t4, {[this]{function_4();}, 1}}
        // {test_type::tn, {[this]{function_n();}, 1}}
    };
};

int main() {

    tester test;
    test.run(test_type::t0, {});
    //test.run(test_type::t1, {1, 2});
    //test.run(test_type::t2, {1, 2, 3});
    //test.run(test_type::t3, {1, 2});
    //test.run(test_type::t4, {1});
    //test.run(test_type::tn, {1});

    return 0;
}
```

so this works since function_0 has 0 parameters and therefore matches `std::function<void()>` type. I am not really sure what the best direction to take from here is.

I *think* there is an option to use variadic `std::function<void(...)>` but reading up on this took me beyond my confort zone and my understanding of variadic templating is not so great.

So my questions are:

- Can this be done with varidic `std::funtion<void(...)>` in some way?
- Is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: What's wrong with passing the `args` vector to the function?

Comment: What you want is not possible. You cannot have `std::function<void(...)>`, it's not valid C++. So you could use raw-function pointer `void (*func)(...)`, but then you can have `this`, or you can put it as the first arg of `func` but then you cannot use lambda with GCC, then you could make it static, but... and the list goes on. You'd better rethink your design at this point, or at least clarify the goal you're trying to achieve with this.

Comment: @erenon in my case this list of functions already exist - I am  just trying to write sort of wrapper to reduce the amount of repeated code. It would be ideal if they all just took an args vector though :)

Comment: Have you considered creating your function a) with the worst case number of parameters (i.e. variables), then assigns all with a default value?  I once implemented a function "int grep(string pfn, string pattern1 = nullptr, string pattern2 = nullptr, ...  string patternN = nullptr);  (N was 5)  For case 0 invoke as int v = grep(pfn);  for case 1 invoke as int v = grep (pfn, p1);  for case 2 invoke as int v = grep(pfn, p1, p2); ... etc.  Operationally, the implementation works thru the 1st parameters, then exits when pJ is nullptr;

Comment: @Holt this was my version of design re-think (well, bolt on!).. you could be right about a larger refactor - I was banking on some sort of variadic std::function or template :(

Comment: @2785528 that is certainly intersting! - but this also requires me to change the existing funcions (which I may have to do by the look of it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the `vector` itself to the wrapper lambdas, and let them extract the `int` values to pass along to their target functions, eg:

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>

enum class test_type {t0, t1, t2, t3, t4, tn};

class tester
{
public:
    void run(test_type type, const std::vector<int> &args)
    {
        func_map[type](args);
    };

private:    
    void function_0()                       { std::cout << "f0\n"; };
    void function_1(int p1, int p2)         { std::cout << "f1\n"; };
    void function_2(int p1, int p2, int p3) { std::cout << "f2\n"; };
    void function_3(int p1, int p2)         { std::cout << "f3\n"; };
    void function_4(int p1)                 { std::cout << "f4\n"; };
    void function_n(int p1)                 { std::cout << "fn\n"; };

    static void validate(const std::vector<int> &args, size_t needed) {
        if (args.size() != needed)
            throw std::invalid_argument("wrong number of arguments");
    }

    using func_type = std::function<void(const std::vector<int> &)>;

    std::map<test_type, func_type> func_map {
        {test_type::t0,
          [this](const std::vector<int> &args){
            validate(args, 0);
            function_0();
          }
        },
        {test_type::t1,
          [this](const std::vector<int> &args){
            validate(args, 2);
            function_1(args[0], args[1]);
          }
        },
        {test_type::t2,
          [this](const std::vector<int> &args){
            validate(args, 3);
            function_2(args[0], args[1], args[2]);
          }
        },
        {test_type::t3,
          [this](const std::vector<int> &args){
            validate(args, 2);
            function_3(args[0], args[1]);
          }
        },
        {test_type::t4,
          [this](const std::vector<int> &args){
            validate(args, 1);
            function_4(args[0]);
          }
        },
        {test_type::tn,
          [this](const std::vector<int> &args){
            validate(args, 1);
            function_n(args[0]);
          }
        },
    };
};

int main() {

    tester test;
    test.run(test_type::t0, {});
    test.run(test_type::t1, {1, 2});
    test.run(test_type::t2, {1, 2, 3});
    test.run(test_type::t3, {1, 2});
    test.run(test_type::t4, {1});
    test.run(test_type::tn, {1});

    return 0;
}
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/22Iady)

Comment: This is certainly better than what I have : )  - I would have llked to find a way to avoid the repeating, but I think that requires more of a larger design change. Thanks  : )